# Corrosion of Ice Auger Blades

Tags: materials, steel, metallurgy, material-science

I am wondering about corrosion of the steel blades on my ice fishing auger. The auger is used on fresh water lakes (ie no salt involved). I have traditionally brought the auger inside to melt the ice off. Then I dry and oil the blades. I am tempted to leave the auger outside over night in the well below freezing temperature. The blades are relatively expensive and impossible to sharpen. I have no idea as to the grade of steel. It does look like a plain carbon steel.

Your thoughts would be appreciated, Grouseman

Comment: What is your question? Does leaving it in the well mean leaving it in sitting in ice? Or water?

Comment: I 'm leaving it outside in the "well below freezing"  temperature. I'm not leaving it in a well.

Comment: Oh okay. You typed this "*I am tempted to leave the auger outside over night in the well*" If the water has frozen I don't think it would corrode. You can test. Get a piece of steel and leave it wet and make sure it rusts. Then clean it off and then stick it in a container of crushed ice and stick the whole thing in the freezer.

Comment: Good idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: Water is oxygenated. Should theoretically be possible to rust it.  Though it'll be slower than liquid water.  If I were to select a coating, I'd try a thin layer of epoxy.

Comment: @Abel I mean...he could paint it except at the edges where it will wear off anyways. But I've heard that sometimes coatings can aggravate things since it will protect the painted surface but then water gets under the paint at the edge of the blade causes worse rust than it otherwise would. Chemical bluing is also an option but I think it has similar concerns...potentially it wouldn't trap water as badly but also would not protect a covered surface as well.

Comment: Will eventually wear, but should last a while even at the edge if he's just cutting ice and not dirt, as some will melt.

Comment: To clarify. These blades are razor sharp. They have a microbevel on them. They do not cut the ice but rather shave the ice. Yes they will dull after drilling about 20 or 30 holes. If the blades are not sharp enough the auger skates all over the ice. Coatings provide no protection to the microbevel edge.